# Notification not showing in android O even after setting up with channel

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to display notification for my music apps. It is working really perfect in below android version 0 but notification is not showing for the versions above android 0. I already set up with channel for above 0 version. But I still can't solve the problem.
This is my NotificationService.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    remoteView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_view);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("JukeTrilll")
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setCustomContentView(remoteView)
                .setAutoCancel(false);
    } else {
        nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("JukeTrilll")
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContent(remoteView)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    }

    notification = nBuilder.build();
    notificationTarget = new NotificationTarget(
            this,
            R.id.img_cover_noti,
            remoteView,
            notification,
            2
    );

    Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(Const.BASE_URL + url).into(notificationTarget);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_song_name_noti, songName);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_artist_name_noti, artist);

    //set the button listeners
    setListeners(remoteView);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Const.ACTION_PREV);
    intentFilter.addAction(Const.ACTION_PAUSE);
    intentFilter.addAction(Const.ACTION_NEXT);
    intentFilter.addAction(Const.ACTION_PLAY);
    registerReceiver(notificationService, intentFilter);

    nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription("desc");
        nBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        nManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }


    assert nManager != null;
    nManager.notify(2, nBuilder.build());
```

And this is myListener class to handle action from notification.

```
        //previous
    Intent volume = new Intent(Const.ACTION_PREV);
    PendingIntent btnPrev = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            0, volume,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_prev_noti, btnPrev);

    //pause
    Intent stop = new Intent(Const.ACTION_PAUSE);
    PendingIntent btnStop = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, stop, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_pause_noti, btnStop);

    //play
    Intent play = new Intent(Const.ACTION_PLAY);
    PendingIntent btnPlay = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, play, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_play_noti, btnPlay);

    //next
    Intent next = new Intent(Const.ACTION_NEXT);
    PendingIntent btnNext = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, next, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_next_noti, btnNext);
```

And finally this is my broadcast receiver class NotificationService.java.

```
  @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        String action = (String) intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Const.ACTION_PREV)) {
            PlayMusicService.prev();
            Song song = PlayMusicService.queueArrayList.get(PlayMusicService.position);
            MyNotificationService.updateNoti(true, song);
            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(2);
        } else if (action.equals(Const.ACTION_PAUSE)) {
            MyNotificationService.updateNotiPlayPause(false);
            PlayMusicService.pauseAudio();
            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(1);
        } else if (action.equals(Const.ACTION_NEXT)) {
            PlayMusicService.next();
            Song song = PlayMusicService.queueArrayList.get(PlayMusicService.position);
            MyNotificationService.updateNoti(true, song);
            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(2);
        } else if (action.equals(Const.ACTION_PLAY)) {
            MyNotificationService.updateNotiPlayPause(true);
            PlayMusicService.unPauseAudio();
            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone please help me to solve this problem.

I already started this service in my activity. All of these are working fine below android O versions.

This is my build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
      }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.devhousemyanmar.juketrill"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    renderscriptTargetApi 17
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-         
rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
realm {
    syncEnabled = true;
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.bottomnavigation:bottom-    
    navigation:2.0.1-rc1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jackandphantom.android:blurimage:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.ryanjeffreybrooks:indefinitepagerindicator:1.0.7'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.github.mmin18:realtimeblurview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing in an emulator ?

Comment: No, I am testing in my two devices one for android 7 and another for android 8.

Comment: same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: @RanjithKP does it make any difference? I'm testing in the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Please try by changing the order.
First,

```
CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription("desc");
        nBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        nManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

then,

```
nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("JukeTrilll")
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setCustomContentView(remoteView)
                .setAutoCancel(false);
```

Comment: can you please change the order of creating channel and building notification. First create channel then build notification.

Comment: I just did that first created channel and building notification. But it still doesn't work yet. :(

Comment: By checking the source  you share i can't tell anything.Can you please share the source in github or somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but `android O` and `compileSdkVersion "27"` not works in my any of projects for notification in oreo and when i change it then it works fine as expected, without making any changes in other code(Notification channels is required)

Use this values for your `build.gradle` it will works defiantly for you i also changed it for oreo notification .

```
android {
compileSdkVersion "26"
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.package.name"
    minSdkVersion '15'
    targetSdkVersion '26'
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
```

Comment: check [this tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developers/migrating-mediastyle-notifications-to-support-android-o-29c7edeca9b7) it will help you

Answer (score -1):

Do this it'll work,

Create channel by this method, call this in your splash activity or any activity that appears first,

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "Your_channel";
        String description = "Your_channel_desc";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

this will create channel now in your FCM service class do this,

```
 private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);

//        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle(mBuilder).bigText(message);

        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setWhen(Long.parseLong(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_small)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setChannelId(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .build();

        final int NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
    }
```

Try this, i have used this code and i am receiving notifications with no issues. I hope it helps.